# Is possible to encrypt only selected files with TrueCrypt?

Tags: usb, encryption, usb-flash-drive, truecrypt

I have a pen drive with some folders in it's root. I want to encrypt all of them except one.

Is possible to do this with TrueCrypt? Maybe this is not the right tool for this task, but I don't know any other.

Comment: Why can't you move the one file, or the other files?

Answer (score 6):

TrueCrypt doesn't encrypt files. It creates encrypted volumes where you can put files. Encrypted volume itself usually resides in a file, so if you leave some space on your pen drive, you can put there that much unencrypted data.